# How to get image dimensions from URL in discord.js

Tags: javascript, image, url, discord.js

I'm using js outside of the browser, so not with html. (I'm using it for discord.js)

I tried a few examples I found on the internet but none of them worked. Is it possible to get the image dimensions without using a library? If not, what library could do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to help here without some code provided. In general, you can return the size of a file in JS using `file.size`.
If you the size in MB, you can do something like this (since file.size always returns bytes):

```
function getSizeInMB (file) {
    return file.size/1024/1024
}
```